# Find the strings from the doc based on so many conditions and store it in the same array

Tags: arrays, powershell

Have a doc containing so many dates as shown below.

```
8/16/2015
7/31/2015
7/23/2015
7/27/2015
5/31/2015
6/30/2015
1/31/2015
```

My requirement is:

```
1. Find the string(s) which has yesterday's date (at the time of execution) -> put it in an array
2. Find the string(s) which has date between last one week (in between (yesterday-8) and yesterday)-> put those in same array
3. Find the string(s) which has date between each week within this month, like if yesterday's date is 16, need to find out how many weeks from 1st of this month till 16th (7 days a week) and find the latest of each week. Maybe the file can have dates both 8/01/2015 and 8/03/2015, both of them coming under 1st week of Aug, so need to take latest (8/03/2015) and -> put it in same array
4. Find the string(s) which is of last month and get the latest of all those -> put it in the same array
5. Find the string(s) which comes in between the last 6 months -> put those in the same array
```

This should be in foreach loop as the doc has got several lines. What I came up with is something like multiple if else statements, some of them having nested loops which I think is not fair and straight.

```
foreach($datec in $datecontent)
{    
 $dc = $datec -split '/'
 $mon = $dc[0]
 $day = $dc[1]
 $year = $dc[2]
 if("$mon/$day/$year" -eq $newdate)
 {
  $array += $datec
 }elseif("$mon/$day/$year" -match $thisweekdays)
 {
  $array += $datec
 }
 ....
 ....
```

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to work with `datetime`objects if you need to compare dates. So the first thing you have to do is to parse the date using the format `M/dd/yyyy`. Then I would write a function foreach criteria you want to filter. I won't implement all your filters, but here is an example for the first one:

```
$entries = @(
    '8/16/2015',
    '7/31/2015',
    '7/23/2015',
    '7/27/2015',
    '5/31/2015',
    '6/30/2015',
    '1/31/2015'
)

function Approve-EntryIsFromYesterday
{
    Param 
    (
        [datetime]$date
    )

    $date.ToString("yyyMMdd") -eq  (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")    
}

$usCulture = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US")
$parseFormat = 'M/dd/yyyy'    

$entries | where { Approve-EntryIsFromYesterday ([datetime]::ParseExact($_, $parseFormat, $usCulture)) }
```

Output:
`8/16/2015`

**Edit to your comment:**

You want to find the latest date of each Week, right?
I wrote a helper function to determine the week of the year called `Get-WeekOfTheYear`. I use this function to group the datetime based of the week and select the oldest one:

```
function Get-WeekOfTheYear
{
    Param 
    (
        [datetime]$date
    )

    $culture = Get-Culture

    $culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
       $date,
       [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek,
       [DayOfWeek]::Monday
    )    
}

function Format-EntryToDate
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$entry
    )

    [datetime]::ParseExact(
        $entry, 
        'M/dd/yyyy', 
        (New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US"))
    )
}

$entries | 
    sort { Format-EntryToDate $_ } -Descending | 
    group { Get-WeekOfTheYear (Format-EntryToDate $_) } | 
    select @{L='Week'; e={$_.Name}}, @{L='Latest Date';e={$_.Group | select -first 1}} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
Week Latest Date
---- -----------
33   8/16/2015  
31   7/31/2015  
30   7/23/2015  
27   6/30/2015  
22   5/31/2015  
5    1/31/2015
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think point#3 says that I need to get those latest of each week within the current month, not entirely. Editing what thing will it enable me to achieve that.?